# How can I center this DIV (CSS/HTML)

Tags: css, html, image, center-align

I have a DIV that I would like centered. There is no defined width or  length because the page is suppose to be versatile with all window sizes (as you re-size window, the page adjusts). I need to keep this, while centering the DIV.

Here are photos of what I mean for visual aid.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL0gB.jpg

The DIV "container" which holds all those images needs to be centered. In the picture it is left aligned with a gap on the right.

Just so it's easier to view, here is the code in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/fZ4CL/

```
#container{
    display:box;
    float:left;
    margin-top:40px;
    left:50%;
}
#thumb{
    display:box;
    float:left;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:5px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.5);}


<body>
<img src='background/001.JPG' class='background'/>
<div id='navigation'>
    <div>
    <ul id='menu'>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Albums</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='toggle'>
        <a href='#'>Hide All</a>
    </div>       
</div>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
    <div id='thumb'><img src='thumbs/thumb.jpg'/></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID. You have multiple elements with an ID of `thumb`. You can't do that. Use classes instead.

Then set the `display` of the thumbnails to `inline-block` and `text-align` of the container to `center`:

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
}
.thumb {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

A few other things wrong in your code:

- `display: box` is very unlikely what you want. You probably want `block` instead.
- `left` and `top` have no effect whatsoever unless `position` is set.
- You seem to have a strange attraction to `float: left` where it is unnecessary.
- I needed to change a `margin` to a `padding` to keep the same spacing.

**[Look at the result.](http://jsfiddle.net/YH6Ak/embedded/result,html,css/)**

Comment: Hey icktoofay, thank you for the tips. It's been awhile since I messed with stuff.

You solutions works perfectly with the small minor problem that the thumbs are being centered as well. Is there any work around to that?

I still want the thumbs to behave left to right and not center.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Oh, I thought that was the effect you desired. If I understand you correctly now, you want it to resize currently except that any extra space the thumbnails can't fill up will be distributed between the left and right of the container? Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that. Sorry.

Comment: It's fine. I can work with it like this, the more major issue was resolved! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

margin: 0 auto; in #container, before the margin-top:

also, why use float: left in the container?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
#container {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't centre a block element unless you give it a defined width. Otherwise the browser will give that element as much width is available, which means it's already centred (with zero space to the left and zero space to the right).

Use `min-width` and/or `max-width` to give the element a defined width which is more flexible than a single `width` value, and then give the element a `margin: 1em auto` style to centre it horizontally within the unused width available in its parent element.